# Is there one universal standard for mathematical notation?

Tags: notation

Lots of different notations are used to mean the same things. For example $\arcsin\left(x\right)$ and $\sin^{-1}\left(x\right)$ mean the same thing usually, but logically $\sin^{-1}\left(x\right)$ would mean $\frac{1}{\sin\left(x\right)}$ which is just $\csc\left(x\right)$, but lots of people simply ignore secant, cosecant and cotangent. I could just go on and on about how goofy modern mathematical notation is, but it's better to have everyone agree on one broken system than to have everyone using their own separate broken systems. Is there like an organisation that comes up with the one true "standard" mathematical notation?

Comment: No, there isn’t. Even if there were, they would be completely unable to enforce their rules.

Comment: There are a lot of such organisations, each trying to enforce their own notation, but almost nobody listens to them. Mandatory xkcd on subject: https://xkcd.com/927/.

Comment: There are some ISO standards for notation in science and engineering, which include some mathematical items.  But not they are not followed by mathematicians.

Comment: Also, even if there were one that a majority of mathematicians agreed were best to use the majority of the time, different contexts change the pros and cons of various notations; the best notation in one context won't be the best in another.